# I created a google screen with html and css and its conflict error

Tags: html, css

Here is a code of html and css of window screen.

Kindly check when zoom in 33% structure is improper button are state outside the main window in whole structure.

I am trying to using width in % but there is no effect i can see.

```css
*
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font: 11px sans-serif;
}
.container
{
 margin: 2%;
 width: 420px;
 height: 320px;
 background-color: #ECE9D8;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px 0 rgba(0,30,160,1), inset 2px 2px 1px 0 #0855DD;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px 0 rgba(0,30,160,1), inset 2px 2px 1px 0 #0855DD;
 box-shadow: inset -2px -2px 1px 0 rgba(0,30,160,1), inset 2px 2px 1px 0 #0855DD;
 border-color: #0855DD #0831D9;
}
.container, .caption_bar
{
 -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
 border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
.sub_container
{
 width: 407px;
 height: 300px;
 padding-top: 7px;
 margin: 0 0 0 8px;
}
.caption_bar
{
 height: 28px;
 background-color: #0055E5;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #3D95FF), color-stop(15, #0055E5), color-stop(88, #4793FF), color-stop(100, #004DE3));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3D95FF 0%, #0055E5 15%, #4793FF 88%, #004DE3 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3D95FF 0%, #0055E5 15%, #4793FF 88%, #004DE3 100%);
 padding-right: 3px;
}
.caption_text
{
 padding-left: 5px;
 line-height: 28px;
 font-size: 13px;
}
.help, .caption_text
{
 font-weight: bold;
}
.btn_container
{
 clear: both;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin: 2px 3px 0 0;
}
.chkbox_container, .btn_container
{
 height: 40px;
}
.right_pan
{
 margin-right: 2px;
 width: 187px;
}
.xp_btn
{
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(80, #F3F3EE), color-stop(100, #D6D0C5));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #F3F3EE 80%, #D6D0C5 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #F3F3EE 80%, #D6D0C5 100%);
 border: 1px solid #003C74;
 padding: 0 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #F1EFEB;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #F1EFEB;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #F1EFEB;
 height: 22px;
 width: 74px;
 margin-right: 1px;
}
.xp_btn, .control_box
{
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 line-height: 19px;
}
.xp_btn:active,.disabled_chkbox
{
 background: #E4E3DD url("last.css"); 
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
}
.xp_btn:focus
{
 outline: 0;
}
.xp_btn[disabled="disabled"]
{
 background: url("last.css") #F5F4EA;
 border-color: #C9C7BA;
}
.control_box
{
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 19px;
 height: 19px;
 border: 1px solid white;
 margin: 3px 0 0 2px;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-align: center;
}
.cross
{
 left: 0;
 position: relative;
 top: 4px;
 margin-left: 2px;
}
.chkbox_container
{
 margin-left: 7px;
}
.btn_container, .chkbox_container, .label_one,.dropdown, .sub_container
{
 overflow: hidden;
}
.check_box
{
 height: 12px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.check, .container
{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
}
.check
{
 width: 11px;
}
.dotted, .check
{
 height: 11px;
}
.check, .xp_btn
{
 vertical-align: bottom;    
}
.enabled_check_box
{
 border-color: #1C5180;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #DBDBD6), color-stop(90, #FFFFFF));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #DBDBD6 0%, #FFFFFF 90%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #DBDBD6 0%, #FFFFFF 90%);
}
.disabled_check_box
{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-color: #CAC8BB;
}
.label_one, .xp_btn[disabled="disabled"]
{
 color: #ACA899;
}
.allow_input:checked ~ .enabled_check_box,
.allow_input:checked ~ .enabled_check_box:hover
{
 background: url("check.png") no-repeat center;
}
.check_box:hover > .enabled_check_box, .enabled_check_box:hover
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #E59700 inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #E59700 inset;
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #E59700 inset;
}
.container input[type="checkbox"]
{
 display: none;
}
.dotted
{
 border: 1px dotted black;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 width: 95.5%;
 margin: 1px;
}
.float_right, .right_pan, .control_box, .image_margin
{
 float: right;
}
.left_pan
{
 width: 212px;
 float: left;
}
.dropdown
{
 width: 88%;   
 height: 19px;
 padding: 0 17px 0 2px;
 background: #FFFFFF url(select_cust.png) no-repeat right;
}
.dropdown, .listbox
{
 margin-top: 3px;
}
.disabled_text
{
 width: 28px;
 height: 18px;    
 background-color: inherit;
}
.inline_controls, .disabled_check_box, .sep, .disabled_text
{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.inline_controls
{
 margin: 4px 0;
}
.sep
{
 width: 120px;
 padding-top: 1px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.inline_controls , .check_box, .sep, .disabled_text, .check
{
 display: inline-block;
}
.listbox
{
 width: 189%;
 height: 142px;
 background: #FFFFFF url('dis_bar.png') no-repeat top right;
}
.listbox, .dropdown, .disabled_text
{
 border: 1px solid #7F9DB9;
}
@media only screen and (min-height:115px) and (max-height:142px){

.listbox 
{ 
    clear: both;
 height: 142px;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cross-reference</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="last.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="cross_ref_form" id="cross_ref_form">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="caption_bar">
                    <span class="caption_text">Cross-reference</span>
     <img src="cross.png" alt="cross.png" class="image_margin cross">
     <img src="help.png" alt="help.png" class="image_margin cross">
                </div>
                <div class="sub_container">
                    <div class="left_right">
                        <div class="left_pan">
                            <label for="ref_type_text">Reference <u>t</u>ype:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="ref_type_text" id="ref_type_text" class="dropdown" value="Numbered item" accesskey="t"/>
                            <div class="check_box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="hyperlink_check_box" id="hyperlink_check_box"  checked="checked" value="insert_hyperlink" class="allow_input"/>
        <div class="enabled_check_box check"></div>
        <label for="hyperlink_check_box" accesskey="h">Insert as <u>h</u>yperlink</label>
       </div>
                            <div class="inline_controls">
                                <div class="check_box">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="seperate_num_check_box" id="seperate_num_check_box" disabled="disabled" value="separate_num"/>
                                    <div class="disabled_check_box check"></div>
                                    <label for="seperate_num_check_box" class="sep label_one">Seperate numbers with</label>
                                </div>
                                <span>
                                    <input type="text" name="seperate_num_text" id="seperate_num_text" disabled="disabled" class="disabled_text">
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="list">
                                <p>For <u>w</u>hich numbered item:</p>
                                <div class="listbox">
                                    <div class="dotted"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right_pan">
                            <label for="insert_ref_text">Insert <u>r</u>eference to:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="insert_ref_text" id="insert_ref_text" class="dropdown" value="Page number" accesskey="r"/>
                            <div class="check_box">
        <input type="checkbox" name="include_check_box" id="include_check_box" accesskey="n" value="include_above_below"/>
        <div class="enabled_check_box check"></div>
        <label for="include_check_box">I<u>n</u>clude above/below</label>
       </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn_container float_right">
                        <span>
                            <button type="button" class="xp_btn" name="insert_btn" id="insert_btn" disabled="disabled">Insert</button>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <button type="button" class="xp_btn" name="cancel_btn" id="cancel_btn">Cancel</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hahahaha did you re-create a Windows XP window? Brilliant.

Comment: you think this is a joke?